# ReportBuilder & Delphi

Tags: delphi, reportbuilder

I have a report created in Report Builder 10.X in an application built with Delphi 7. Is there a way to automatically shrink it to print 1 page wide? I want to give the users flexibility of printing on different paper sizes but always know it will shrink to 1 page wide.